# Allowing .rfa Files In Media Upload

Tags: plugins, uploads, media-library

I'm using the plugin File Upload Types, trying to allow .rfa uploads.  I've tried the three MIME types below to no avail.  Do you have any suggestions?

application/octet-stream
application/rfa
application/CDFV2-unknown

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allowing all/different file type uploads](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/290828/allowing-all-different-file-type-uploads)

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, was able to figure it out.  It is application/CDFV2 as of WP 5.5.3